# How gradle get all the dependencies of a third party library?

Tags: gradle, jar, jvm

In my springboot application (kotlin+gradle) I'm trying to use one of my libraries stored in Nexus. This nexus-library needs some dependencies from AWS sdk and other repositories.

Must I configure gradle.build.kts with all the repositories needed to fetch all these extra dependencies?, does it know gradle where are all these dependencies directly from the Jar?,  or.....how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle will use the POM file for the dependency to work out any transitive dependencies, and will attempt to retrieve them from your configured repository. If they are not available directly from there then you'll need to add additional repositories into your Gradle configuration to tell Gradle where it can search for these dependencies.

Comment: Depending on how the dependency was published and Gradle version, the POM will be ignored entirely in favor of [Gradle Module Metadata](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_gradle_module_metadata.html)

Answer (score 1):

For Gradle version 6, Gradle will try to resolve a dependency in the following order

1. Gradle module metadata (a JSON file with .module extention)
2. Maven metadata (.pom file) or Ivy metadata (.ivy file) depending on Maven or Ivy repository respectively
3. The artifact(E.g., jar) itself if no metadata is found. This has been disabled but can be enabled through an additional configuration.

See [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.4/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:supported_metadata_sources) for more information.